# Remove // after domain name using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

i have site there both url are working as follow

https://domainname/abc

https://domainname//abc

so i just want to redirect //abc to 404 error page for preventing duplicate content i try following rule but didn't work.

```
RewriteRule ^//(.*)$ 404
ErrorDocument 404 https://domain_name/404
```

i also try using RedirectMatch as follow

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    RedirectMatch 404 ^//(.*)$ https://domain_name/$1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to identify and fix the actual cause of those requested URLs instead of trying to cure the symptom?

Comment: When configured in .htaccess context, the URL path a RewriteRule matches against never starts with a leading slash, that has already been stripped off at this point. (And I doubt that `//` at the start would result in only one of them being removed, and the other one “surviving”.) You will probably have to use a RewiteCond here, to check the content if the `REQUEST_URI` variable, I suppose that should still contain `//abc` here in this case. (And if that should turn out not to be the case, you could still go with `THE_REQUEST`.)